# Not responding issue with the wxpython

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I'm quite new to wxpython, yet to learn process or threading.
I have been checking online for my problem with non -responsive window whenever the data is processed. I have seen quite a few examples online but I couldnt find a solution to my issue (probably i'm not getting the point) cos i do not use thread, its just a normal simple program that uses a while loop and it has to be inside the while loop for around 150secs, at the same time i have redirected the print text to the log window, which gets freezed as well the window shows not responding when i go to someother tab while this program is under process kindly suggest me the solution. 
The code goes like this
i have used Mike's logic in redirecting the text.

```
class RedirectText(object):
    def __init__(self,aWxTextCtrl):
        self.out=aWxTextCtrl

    def write(self,string):
        self.out.WriteText(string)

Class GUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # All the frame work
        # redirected print to the stdout

    def run(self, input):
        #calls another operation 
        self.set_BankID(BankID, serSCU,SerialLogResult)

    def set_BankID(self,BankID, serSCU,SerialLogResult):
        #while loop
        iteration=0
        While iteration < 3:
            wx.Yield()
            while process = 0:
                wait 150 secs
            #end of inner while loop
            #condition met for iteration
         #End of outer while loop

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=wx.App(False)
    frame =GUI(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are blocking the main loop, so the GUI can no longer update itself. You'll want to put that long running process into a thread and use one of wxPython threadsafe methods to send updates to the GUI. Those methods are as follows:

- wx.CallAfter / wx.CallLater
- wx.PostEvent

You can read about various approaches at the following locations:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

I prefer using wx.CallAfter as I think it's the simplest.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for your response, i used this link,http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks. to redirect my wxTextCtl, but still its not working as expected, its coming out of that loop after few seconds, but its not showing me any error, it neither says anything else, on the GUI but its getting stopped somewhere in the middle of the configuraion process.

Comment: I guess once it comes out to write the log from the while loop, it couldn't continue the same point where it left.could you please suggest me if you know any solution for this?

Comment: You would want to send your updates inside your while loops. As I said, you'll either have to tell us what your process is doing, or you'll just have to post an update every once in a while.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thankyou so much. Wx.CallAfter works perfect without much of hassle. Used your link without the usage of pubsub, as my output is different, and updated the sleep time according to my requirements. its working as expected now.